# C# - How to trigger Windows Security to prompt for credentials when trying to access directory thats requires authentication?

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint

I'm working on a project to access SharePoint folders and open them directly with Windows Explorer. When opening the folder manually (Open explorer and directly type in the exact SharePoint folder path),it prompts for my Active Directory login to authenticate and provide read/write access. Once I have done this once it won't ask again until I reboot.

My issue is when I try to access a folder for the first time with my code, it just spits me out into a generic path (like My PC or Documents). It appears that it tries to access the folder, realizes I don't have access, and defaults to basic explorer window.

Is there any way for me to check for read/write access, check if credentials are required, and trigger the default Windows Security window to ask for authentication? I'm really trying to avoid handling user credentials with my code. Below is what I'm currently using to open the folder.

```
string foldername = @"Sample Project Folder";
Process.Start("explorer.exe",@"\\sp.companyname.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\dc\Projects\" + foldername);
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SharePoint does *not* ask for credentials, it knows who the current user is. The only case it does so is if the current user does *not* have permissions or isn't recognized, eg because it's a local account or an account in a different domain. If the current user *has* permissions, there's a configuration problem.

Comment: In any case SharePoint is a web application. The full path to a document is a URL, not a file share. File shares are emulated using WebDAV. If you know the document's URL you can use eg HttpClient or WebClient to retrieve the file using the default network credentials

Comment: Explorer should open with an authentication error. I believe your path is incorrect. That is what causes it to open on a default view.

Comment: As long as I have logged in already than the path I posted works perfectly. Originally I didn't have the @SSL\DavWWWRoot in the path, and it would take 5-30 seconds to open in explorer.